# How to get featured image thumbnail instead of cropping automatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm working on a gallery for the homepage of this site: [Warm Glow Photo](http://warmglowphoto.com/wp2015/)

I have called the featured image at a specific size (800x600) that I have defined in functions.php. This seems to be calling

```
...IMAGE.jpg?resize=800%2C600
```

instead of the version of the featured image called

```
...IMAGE-800x600.jpg
```

I am using a plug-in for cropping thumbnails which means I need to call this image rather than cropping with **?resize**.

I've found lots of info about how to call different size thumbnails but nothing that explains why it crops with **?resize** instead of calling the different thumbnail itself. Any ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated.

The relevant code is:

```
<?php 
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
      echo '<li><a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
      the_post_thumbnail( 'bones-thumb-800' );
      echo '</a></li>';
  }
?>
```

and defining `bones-thumb-800` in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-800', 800, 600, true );
```

Comment: Which plugin? It's hard to comment without knowing what is generating the URL's in the first place. It probably works by sending the resize information as a URL parameter (resize) instead of tacking items onto the file name.

Comment: It's a plugin called Image Regenerate & Select Crop. But I'm coding the theme myself so the URL is generated by my code which is doing exactly what you say, resizing with a URL parameter rather than adding something to the file name. This means it's cropping from the centre of the image. The plugin generates a thumbnail of your chosen crop so I need it to call that rather than changing the URL parameter. The code calling the thumbnail is `the_post_thumbnail( 'bones-thumb-800' );`

Comment: Share your code that generate the URL then

Comment: You're sure that the thumb size `bones-thumb-800` is defined in your functions.php ? If so could you share the code ? The more information we have the easier it is to help.
By the way, please edit your original post instead posting code in comments - it's really hard to read.

Comment: Thanks vard, I've shared the code from functions.php that defines `bones-thumb-800` and moved the code into the original post.. much clearer!

Answer (score 0):

To get the plain URL of a post use this function :

```
function um_get_post_featured_image_src($post_id = null,$size = "full"){
    if(!$post_id){
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), $size );
        return $image[0];
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

If you have a **$post** globally than you don't need to pass post ID.

Comment: Thanks for that Burimi! I haven't had a chance to try it out but will let you know how I get on.